# What would be the American equivalent of "sheer bloody-mindedness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The term is very British, and one of Douglas Adams' pet phrases, as in:

> Meanwhile, the natural forces on the planet Vogsphere had been working
> overtime to make up for their earlier blunder. They brought forth
> scintillating jewelled scuttling crabs, which the Vogons ate, smashing
> their shells with iron mallets; tall aspiring trees with breathtaking
> slenderness and colour which the Vogons cut down and burned the crab
> meat with; elegant gazelle-like creatures with silken coats and dewy
> eyes which the Vogons would catch and sit on. They were no use as
> transport because their backs would snap instantly, but the Vogons sat
> on them anyway [...] out of **sheer bloody-mindedness**.

Or:

> Vogons suffered no illusions as to the regard their works were
> generally held in. Their early attempts at composition had been part
> of a bludgeoning insistence that they be accepted as a properly
> evolved and cultured race, but now the only thing that kept them going
> was **sheer bloody-mindedness**.

"Out of spite" doesn't quite cut it, does it?

The reason it doesn't cut it (and why neutral words, such as stubborness, obstinacy, etc, etc. don't cut it either) is this:

Bloody-mindedness implies, not merely a person's implacability, but also a touch of casual malice and a whole lot of spite.

Answer (score 4):

A colorful alternative is **pigheadedness** (or *pig-headedness*), from the adjective *pigheaded*, defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pigheaded) as "willfully or perversely unyielding". Since Merriam-Webster is an American dictionary and this isn't marked as a UK English usage, it is fine in US English. The association with pigs means it's almost invariably derogatory. The [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pig-headed) suggests it might come from the refusal of a driven pig to go in the direction you want or expect.

**Stubbornness** is an obvious synonym in US and UK English; Merriam-Webster's first definition of [stubborn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stubbornness) is "unreasonably or perversely unyielding". But it can also mean someone who is resolute in their refusal without that refusal being unreasonable (as M-W says: "justifiably unyielding") so it doesn't always imply malice or spite, but it is a word most people will know.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I think of a stubborn American (not, I admit, very often) I think of words such as:

*ornery*

for which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ornery) gives the definition

> *adjective*
>
> having an irritable disposition : CANTANKEROUS

and

*mulish*

for which the same source, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mulish), gives

> *adjective*
>
> unreasonably and inflexibly obstinate

and

*muleheaded* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muleheaded))

> *adjective*
>
> STUBBORN, PIGHEADED

Merriam-Webster lists *orneriness* and *mulishness* as nouns related to the adjectives but not, sadly, *muleheadedness*, though I don't see why its absence from that dictionary (nor from the other two dictionaries I consulted) should stop anyone using it.

I think any of these words could replace *bloody-mindedness*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Britishism that has nothing to do with literal blood.

> **bloody-minded** *adj*
> 2. *Chiefly British* Perversely cantankerous or obstructive.
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://thefreedictionaryonline.com/bloody-minded)</sub>

So perversity or cantankerousness would serve. Look in that direction.

Comment: *perversity* wouldn't serve at all, it's often taken to mean something akin to *(sexual) deviance*.  In an expression such as *perverse cantakerousness*, the adjective might form part of an answer to the question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark One of the definitions of *perversity* is "**persistently holding to what is wrong**"; which sounds like just the thing here. Just because one definition of a word doesn't suit you, does that mean none will? In your comment, **serve** is also a tennis term; perhaps that should be disqualified as well?

Answer (score 0):

***spite***

is the simplest equivalent, but if you want something that sounds more stereotypically American, you could do worse than

***cussedness***

> mean-spirited disagreeable contrariness

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cussedness)

> None of us can have as many virtues as the fountain-pen, or half its cussedness; but we can try.

-Mark Twain

(and yes, ***contrariness*** will work just as well)